# Frechet derivative of bilinear map

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $f:X \times Y\rightarrow Z $ is a bilinear map, I'm trying to calculate the Frechet derivative using the definition. I've tried the following with $(x,y), (h,k) \in X \times Y $.
  So $$\|f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)-A_{(x,y)}(h,k)\|_Z=\|f(x,k)+f(h,y)+f(h,k)-A_{(x,y)}(h,k)\|_Z $$
Now if we set $A_{(x,y)}(h,k)=f(x,k)+f(h,y)+f(h,k) $ then the expressions above are 0 and so surely A is the frechet derivative, I know this isn't right but why is this the case?
($X, Y, Z $ are normed spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Because the function $A_{(x,y)}$ is not linear. Observe that for $(a,b),(c,d)\in X\times Y$ we have that
$$A_{(x,y)}((a,b)+(c,d))=A_{(x,y)}(a+c,b+d)\neq A_{(x,y)}(a,b)+A_{(x,y)}(c,d)$$

Comment: So how should I go about actually finding the frechet derivative using the definition of the derivative?

Comment: well, you can try to show that $f(h,k)\in o(\|(h,k)\|)$, and that the function defined by $A_{(x,y)}(h,k):=f(x,k)+f(h,y)$ is linear. For the first task observe that $\|f(h,k)\|\le\|f\|\|h\|\|k\|$ and that $\|(h,k)\|\le C\|(h,k)\|_\infty$ for some constant $C>0$

Comment: sorry, the last inequality in my previous comment is not useful. Instead you can consider the inequalities $$\|(h,k)\|\ge\|h\|\quad\text{and}\quad\|(h,k)\|\ge\|k\|$$

Comment: We are given that f is bounded so the inequalities are useful anyway